# CSS Transition between 2 icons (Material Design)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Is possible change className of ID with a smooth transition between elements?
Using CSS Transition? or Changing opacity of .mdi-star?

https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/n3gjfcvp/1/

```
<script>
function changeFavButtonClass(){
if ( document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className == 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline' ){
   document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className = 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star';
}else{
   document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className = 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline';
}
}
</script>

<i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline" onclick="changeFavButtonClass()"></i>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some CSS animation and keyframes. Take a look what I did here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ko9nx4mt/1/

```js
function changeFavButtonClass(){
  if ( document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className == 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline' ){
  document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className = 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star';
  }else{
  document.getElementById("fav_button_icon").className = 'mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline';
  }
}
```

```css
.mdi-star-outline{
  animation:fade1 1s linear;
}

.mdi-star{
  animation:fade2 1s linear;
}


@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.8.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline" onclick="changeFavButtonClass()"></i>
```

Comment: Very strange effect :-/

Comment: @FeKuLa what are you looking for? You asked for a transition with opacity and that's exactly what I gave you.

Comment: @FeKuLa Let me know if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ko9nx4mt/2/

Answer (score 0):

To have a real nice effect between the outlined and full star, like I think you want:

You have to use a container to absolute position the full star over the outlined one with opacity at zero.

Then on click, just change the opacity... A CSS `transition` will then work.

```js
let fullStarState = false;
function changeFavButtonClass() {
  fullStarState = !fullStarState;
  document.querySelector(".star-full").style.opacity = Number(fullStarState)
}
```

```css
.icon-wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.star-full{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.8.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="icon-wrap" onclick="changeFavButtonClass()">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

You probably want more than one star in the page...

Here is a better variant of the JS.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".icon-wrap").forEach(function(star){
  star.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    let full = this.querySelector(".star-full")
    let star_opacity = full.style.opacity
    full.style.opacity = (star_opacity) ? 0 : 1
  })
})
```

```css
.icon-wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.star-full{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.8.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star-outline"></i>
  <i id="fav_button_icon" class="mdi mdi-48px mdi-star star-full"></i>
</div>
```